# Simple Modal - more than one

Tags: jquery-plugins

I'm using the simplemodal-demo-basic-1.4.1 and iam having trouble using it to open more than one window on a page (I don't need them to open at the same time or on top of one another).
I tried adding another class and calling out that class in my js file, but I'm not getting it.  I'm sure I'm missing something. -Can someone please help?

Comment: Please post your code and if possible a link to a page demonstrating your problem.

Comment: Even though I'm a ninja, I don't want to break into your house and steal your code just to debug it. Mind doing that for me?

Comment: @Blender - Yes, but if you did, would anyone know? :P

Comment: I'm a ninja who breaks into houses and installs Linux onto peoples' computers. Some call it vandalism; I call it a favor.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're talking about the [demo available on the simplemodal Google Code project](http://code.google.com/p/simplemodal/downloads/detail?name=simplemodal-demo-basic-1.4.1.zip&can=2&q=)

Here's what I had to do to add a second modal dialog to that demo:

Add the following HTML to index.html:

- inside the `content` div:

  ```
  <!-- second modal content -->
  <div id="basicTwo-modal-content">
    <h3>Basic Two Modal Dialog</h3>
    <p>The Second Modal</p>
  </div>
  ```
- inside the `basic-modal` div:

  ```
  <input type='button' name='basicTwo' value='Demo Two' class='basicTwo'/> or <a href='#' class='basicTwo'>Demo Two</a>
  ```

Add the following CSS to basic.css:

```
    #basicTwo-modal-content { display: none; }
```

Add the following JavaScript to basic.js inside the jQuery load handler:

```
    $('#basic-modal .basicTwo').click(function (e) {
      $('#basicTwo-modal-content').modal();

      return false;
    });
```

**[Working Demo](http://brian.peiris.name/so/5774459/)**